# What should be a correct JSON response for actions on certain object(s)

Tags: json, rest, design-patterns

What should be a correct JSON response for actions on certain object(s). I would like to perform a certain action on User(s).

I am assuming the REST syntax for such actions (either single or multiple) look fine, what should a sample JSON response look like in case of success or failures.

e.g.

```
a. Archive a certain User http://foo:port/users/1/archive
b. Archive User(s) http://foo:port/users/archive?userIds=1,2,3
c. Remove a certain User http://foo:port/users/1/remove
d. Remove User(s) http://foo:port/users/remove?userIds=1,2,3
```

Comment: I would say those requests don't need a Json response, a correct http status code should be sufficient

Comment: What if the action is taken on 3 users, 2 succeeded and 1 failed. Do I need to propagate the status of each user separately in the response?

Comment: I you have three actions this should be three calls to the REST service, each of them can succeed or fail.

Comment: @marged Its not 3 actions, but a single action against 3 users of which some could fail and some succeed.

Comment: As far as I know REST is resource oriented, that means one url refers to one entity. That means three users = three entities = three urls

Comment: @Marged This is about bulk updating resources, what would be the pattern here?